# Setting the text of an <option> element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Using jQuery what is the best way of editing option text for a given select value.

I know the value of the option I want to edit.  I thought it would be something like...

```
$('#select').val().$('option').html('New Text');
```

But I am clearly missing something.

Comment: $('#select option:selected').text("new text")

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('#select option[value="someValue"]').text("newText")
```

could use `.html` instead of `.text`, if adding html content.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
$('#select').children('option').text('New Text');
```

Have a look at [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information on selecting the correct item. You could do something like

```
$('#select').children('option:first').text('New Text');
```

Or you can use

```
$('#select').children('option[value="thevalue"]').text('New Text');
```

If you know the value.

Comment: none of them works for me and you have an error in .children.
there is no dot after children

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector and the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("#select option:selected").text("New Text");
```

Answer (score 3):

This one help you to get the options value,

```
$('#select_id').children('option[value="thevalue"]').text('New Text');
```

And you can set default selected value by using `prop()` function. Take  an example [here](http://kvcodes.com/2014/03/set-html-select-options-selected-value-using-jquery/).